# expression to Calculate percentage in ssrs

Tags: expression, ssrs-2008, percentage

What is the expression if I want to find the percentage of 50 of the total of 
524?

Valid Consent
50
35
42
18
15
16
22
48
64
18
30
28
37
41
22
38

Answer (score 0):

**Ass**u**me**ing that your data is in a table's field named CONSENT and using Dataset1, your table's detail expression could be

```
=Fields!CONSENT.Value / SUM(Fields!CONSENT.Value, "Dataset1")
```

This will take a single value from the CONSENT field in a table and divide it by the total of all CONSENT fields in Dataset1.